# Redirecting with a decoupled front and back end

Tags: javascript, rest, express, redirect, cross-domain

I've an express server with my front-end on it, and one with my REST API.

My front-end can access the back-end routes fine, but I'd like to be able to redirect the front-end to a different page (on that same front-end server) depending on logic in that route, and I'm not sure exactly how to do that when they're decoupled like this?

In my back-end route I'm currently trying to use:

```
res.redirect('http://frontendIP:port/pageIWantToGetTo.html');
```

and that resulted in a no 'access-control-allow-origin' header error.

So I added the header to my webpack config, which solved that error

```
devServer: {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    },
```

My front end recognises the redirect (in the network tab)

`login.html 200 xhr`

and the initiator is recorded as`:8080/correctBackendRoute`

but the page isn't changing at all. Am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks

*Edit: Thinking about it, does a redirect even make sense? Really it should be telling the front end to serve another html file, rather than make a request elsewhere. I feel a little out of my depth!

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for the reply. Nah, I'm ok with the authorisation part, it's redirecting that I'm struggling with.

Comment: Your back-end shouldn't care about anything going on on the front-end. It should just sent the signal that the request was successful or not. That's it. Your front-end should decide what to do about it, whether that's redirection, showing a different page, or blowing up. That last one might be a little extreme :).

Comment: Yeah of course, thanks - I think I confused myself by trying to mimick a coupled server using template engines - which doesn't make sense. I think you've also cleared up my other problem, which was how to prevent people accessing front-end pages when the auth is on the back end route :)  (front-end => req => res denied => frontend redirect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your frontend is doing an API call, and that API call is replying with a redirect, I would not expect the frontend itself to switch to a new page. Only where you made the API call itself, that client should follow the redirect and hit it after.

If you want your backend to communicate to the frontend: please refresh the document and go to this new url, I think that is a *bit* unusual. That kind of logic is usually baked into the frontend code.

Think about this is way, if there's multiple clients hitting your API, it would be weird if the API replied with something that only makes sense for your frontend.

Comment: Yeah I got myself completely confused trying to replicate a server that redirects to different templates. Obviously the frontend would wait for a response and then redirect itself based on that :)

Thanks